# How to get Google API access code using Code in windows phone 8.1 App?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am new in Windows phone application development.

I have created my app in Google developer Console.
From my windows phone application I am using "webview" to render the Google login page and with successfull login I got a code like: `4/akd........`.

Can anyone tell me how to access the code using "code" first time ?

I have try by following way :

```
public void GetProfileDetail(string code) 
{
    StringBuilder authLink = new StringBuilder();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    authLink.AppendFormat("code={0}", code);
    authLink.AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", clientId);
    authLink.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", clientSecret);
    authLink.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", redirect_url);
    authLink.Append("&grant_type=authorization_code");

    UTF8Encoding utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = utfenc.GetBytes(authLink.ToString());
    Stream os = null;


    try // send the post
    {
        //webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length; // Count bytes to send

        os = webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result;
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);        // Send it
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

but it gives me an error. Let me know what to do next

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do the OAuth authentication through the webview, but that is not the recommended way to go.

Since wp8.1 there is a `WebAuthenticationBroker` class that you can use to initiate an OAuth process with a provider ( like Google in your case ).

A good detailed example can be found on MSDN here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122